# Email to SMS - Setting the sender email address

Tags: sms

My software has the ability to send an SMS via email. E.g: It sends an email to 12345678@vtext.com which will automatically send it as an SMS to the mobile number 12345678.

This was working fine when I was using PHPMailer 2. However my server upgraded their PHP version and PHPMailer 2 stoped working. I've now upgraded to PHPMailer 5.

Now when an Email to SMS is sent, the recipient receives the SMS but the sender that is displayed on the phone is set to myaccount@myserverdomain.com rather than the sender's email address like before.

Has anyone had any experience with Email to SMS and getting the correct sender to show in the phone?

I've tried adding additional headers like 'Reply-to' and 'Sender' to the messages but to no avail.

**EDIT:**

As I am in Australia I have been unable to run my own tests as Email to SMS doesn't work here. I have a customer in the USA I am working with. These are headers when sending tests to my desktop computer.

I've removed the email addresses for security reasons. They are [to_email_address] and [from_email_address]. elvanto AT vps.devsyndicate DOT com is an email address that doesn't exist but this is the sender on my clients mobile phone. I have changed this to [server_email_address].

Some differences I found in the headers:

Version 2

```
Received: from localhost.localdomain ([127.0.0.1]:58857 helo=mychurch.elvanto.com) by vps.devsyndicate.com with esmtp (Exim 4.80.1) (envelope-from <[from_email_address]>) id 1Uv6cP-0002oV-Hq for [to_email_address]; Sat, 06 Jul 2013 00:04:13 +1000
```

Version 5

```
Received: from elvanto by vps.devsyndicate.com with local (Exim 4.80.1) (envelope-from <[server_email_address]>) id 1Uv6ds-0002rF-Cc for [to_email_address]; Sat, 06 Jul 2013 00:05:44 +1000
```

Version 2

```
Return-Path: <[from_email_address]>
Received-Spf: pass (google.com: domain of [from_email_address] designates 64.64.28.228 as permitted sender) client-ip=64.64.28.228;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of [from_email_address] designates 64.64.28.228 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=[from_email_address]
```

Version 5

```
Return-Path: <[server_email_address]>
Received-Spf: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of [server_email_address] designates 64.64.28.228 as permitted sender) client-ip=64.64.28.228;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of [server_email_address] designates 64.64.28.228 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=[server_email_address]
```

Full headers from PHPMailer 2:

```
Delivered-To: [to_email_address]
Received: by 10.223.7.199 with SMTP id e7csp124282fae; Fri, 5 Jul 2013 07:05:18 -0700 (PDT)
Received: from vps.devsyndicate.com (vps.devsyndicate.com. [64.64.28.228]) by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id du5si5410404obb.84.2013.07.05.07.05.17 for <[to_email_address]> (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128); Fri, 05 Jul 2013 07:05:17 -0700 (PDT)
Received: from localhost.localdomain ([127.0.0.1]:58857 helo=mychurch.elvanto.com) by vps.devsyndicate.com with esmtp (Exim 4.80.1) (envelope-from <[from_email_address]>) id 1Uv6cP-0002oV-Hq for [to_email_address]; Sat, 06 Jul 2013 00:04:13 +1000
X-Received: by 10.182.40.132 with SMTP id x4mr11299384obk.61.1373033117984; Fri, 05 Jul 2013 07:05:17 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <[from_email_address]>
Received-Spf: pass (google.com: domain of [from_email_address] designates 64.64.28.228 as permitted sender) client-ip=64.64.28.228;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of [from_email_address] designates 64.64.28.228 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=[from_email_address]
Message-Id: <371a5f588e69a11fbc8439aca9a7e367@mychurch.elvanto.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer (phpmailer.sourceforge.net) [version 2.0.4]
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
X-Antiabuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-Antiabuse: Primary Hostname - vps.devsyndicate.com
X-Antiabuse: Original Domain - elvanto.com
X-Antiabuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [47 12] / [47 12]
X-Antiabuse: Sender Address Domain - elvanto.com
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: vps.devsyndicate.com: acl_c_authenticated_local_user: elvanto
```

Full headers from PHPMailer 5:

```
Delivered-To: [to_email_address]
Received: by 10.223.7.199 with SMTP id e7csp124309fae; Fri, 5 Jul 2013 07:05:46 -0700 (PDT)
Received: from vps.devsyndicate.com (vps.devsyndicate.com. [64.64.28.228]) by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id at5si5435775obc.27.2013.07.05.07.05.44 for <[to_email_address]> (version=TLSv1 cipher=RC4-SHA bits=128/128); Fri, 05 Jul 2013 07:05:45 -0700 (PDT)
Received: from elvanto by vps.devsyndicate.com with local (Exim 4.80.1) (envelope-from <[server_email_address]>) id 1Uv6ds-0002rF-Cc for [to_email_address]; Sat, 06 Jul 2013 00:05:44 +1000
X-Received: by 10.60.52.16 with SMTP id p16mr11209612oeo.29.1373033145381; Fri, 05 Jul 2013 07:05:45 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <[server_email_address]>
Received-Spf: pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of [server_email_address] designates 64.64.28.228 as permitted sender) client-ip=64.64.28.228;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: best guess record for domain of [server_email_address] designates 64.64.28.228 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=[server_email_address]
Message-Id: <7d22d8f7c388c9e92c938391240a374b@mychurch.elvanto.com>
X-Priority: 3
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.1 (http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
X-Antiabuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-Antiabuse: Primary Hostname - vps.devsyndicate.com
X-Antiabuse: Original Domain - elvanto.com
X-Antiabuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [530 529] / [47 12]
X-Antiabuse: Sender Address Domain - vps.devsyndicate.com
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: vps.devsyndicate.com: authenticated_id: elvanto/from_h
```

Comment: Can you post the MAIL headers here? If you can post both old PHPMailer and 2.0 version MAIL headers.

Comment: @dougEfresh I've added the headers as requested :)

Comment: @dougEfresh I found if I use $phpmailer->Sender it will update the Return-Path and Received-Spf headers. It worked fine on my desktop computer so I'll run a test with my customer in the USA and see if this solves it! Thanks again for suggesting looking at the headers!